# codename one what does uiid mean

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

[image of the label components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDors.jpg)

Hi i wanted to know what uiid mean and i also wanted to know how can use it in code. I want to access the label id from the gui builder to use in code for example i want to change the colour in code.

Comment: No that's UUID (Universal Unique Identifier). See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Codename One UIID means "UI ID" User Interface Identifier. It's roughly equivalent to the CSS `class` attribute. In that way you can determine how something will look e.g. if you want a text field to look like a button just do:

```
myTextField.setUIID("Button");
```

And it will work.

You can also just make up ID's e.g. "MyUIID". Then you can use CSS or the theme designer to define the styling for it globally. See [this](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/css.html) to learn how to use CSS in Codename One.

See [this](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-create-gorgeous-sidemenu.html) for a sample of working with UIIDs and the designer tool.

You can also use the component inspector tool from the simulator menu to see UIIDs live and interact with them within the simulator.